# HttpClient doesn't send request with json with russian characters

Tags: json, httpclient, flutter

I make client app and I use HttpClient. It perfectly sends and gets json with latin symbols, but when I try to send json with russian letters (with the same request address and server), it doesn't send any requests to server.
Here is the code:

```
  class RestApiClientBase {

  static String _server;
  static String _ssid;
  final HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
  static const _codec = const JsonEncoder.withIndent(" ");

  RestApiClientBase() {
    _client.badCertificateCallback =
        (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true; //for self-signed cert
  }

  void setServer(String serverNew) {
    _server = serverNew;
  }

  void setSsid(String ssidNew) {
    _ssid = ssidNew;
  }

  dynamic invokePost(String method, String data) async {
    return await _client.postUrl(Uri.parse(_server + method))
        .then((HttpClientRequest request) async {
      //print('11111111111111111111111');
      request.headers.contentType
      = new ContentType("application", "json", charset: "utf-8");
      //print('22222222222222222222222');
      request.contentLength = data.length;
      //print('33333333333333333333333');
      request.write(data);
      //print('44444444444444444444444');
      return await request.close();
    })
        .then((HttpClientResponse response) async {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response
            .transform(UTF8.decoder)
            .single;
      } else {
        String errorJson = RestApiClientBase._codec.convert(
            {
              "status": "error",
              "message": "Error code: ${response.statusCode}"
            });
        return errorJson;
      }
    }).then((String answer) async {
      var json = JSON.decode(answer);
      rState.setRState(method, json["status"], json["message"]);
      return json;
    });
  }
}
class SecurityGroupClient extends RestApiClientBase {
  dynamic getSGroups() async {
    String json = RestApiClientBase._codec.convert(
        {"ssid": RestApiClientBase._ssid});
    return await invokePost("sgroup/list", json);
  }

  dynamic createSGroup(String name, String info) async {
    String json = RestApiClientBase._codec.convert(
        {"ssid": RestApiClientBase._ssid, "name": name, "info": info});
    print(json);
    return await invokePost("sgroup/create", json);
  }
}
```

I get all messages (111,222,333,444), but then I don't get anything else.
Here is the example of json:

> {
>   "ssid": "6a3b1d12-cd4d-4962-ae06-34d36e31ac7e",
>   "name": "Тестовая группа на русском",
>   "info": "тест"
>   }
>   Server uses https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because of wrong contentLength. By default content is UTF8 encoded. So actually data length != string length. If you run console application it will throw an Exception

> Content size exceeds specified contentLength. 69 bytes written while
>   expected 38.

So best solution to get encoded length is:

```
request.contentLength = UTF8.encode(data).length;
```